# how do i fill available space in stacklayout?

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform

hi i need to fill the screen width with an horizontal stacklayout but it doesnt fill

here is my code

```
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

           <Entry Placeholder="Nombre" FontSize="14" />
           <Entry Placeholder="A. Paterno" FontSize="14" />
           <Entry Placeholder="A. Materno" FontSize="14" />
   </StackLayout>
```

I already try this way with the horizontalOptions = "Fill" and also "Fill and Expand" as well I already try put in a AbsoluteLayout this way

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"> 
        <Entry Placeholder="Nombre" FontSize="14" />
        <Entry Placeholder="A. Paterno" FontSize="14" />
        <Entry Placeholder="A. Materno" FontSize="14" />
     </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Any other idea?

Comment: Replace the StackLayout with a Grid with one `auto` row and three `1*` columns. It should divide the space evenly.

Comment: You want to display All entry with same width?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display All Entry with same width and Fill horizontally then Try below code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Entry Placeholder="Nombre" FontSize="14"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="A. Paterno" FontSize="14" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="A. Materno" FontSize="14" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
```